# Jquery animating child using destination offset with parent set to position relative

Tags: jquery

I've some serious problems with animating little image from 1 place to another.

I get destination offset and try to animate my image towards desired location using offset content as coordinates. But it always ends up incorrect.

I understand the problem is position:relative, position:absolute; But I cannot get rid of these becuase of the the layout I've...

Is there a better way to calculate coordinates against window?

I made simplified fiddle so you can see what I mean...

http://jsfiddle.net/9WMGk/1/

```
$("#thirdBA a").on("click", function(){
    $("#thirdBA").append('<p class="animated">This is me</p>');
    var offset = $("#second").offset();
    console.dir(offset.left);
    console.dir(offset.top);
    $(".animated").animate({left: offset.left, top: offset.top},"slow");
});
```

When you click link box is appended. And than it must move to "come here" div.

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just animate to based on position of second div ie: `$('#second').position()`
view the fiddle below for more info

http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/9WMGk/3/

let me know 
-David

Comment: Well, you made manual corrections to the position output. That's not gonna work...